# Setting fetch timeout in Avaya Experience Portal

Tags: web-services, ivr, avaya

I have a speech project which uses web service. I have set the timeout for 45 seconds in OD but when I deploy it, I get the following error for the first calling user in EP log viewer:

Fetch time out when opening timed stream for url =
http://example.com/AppName/SetLanguage?___DDSESSIONID=EF3397385F3E9BC0E89D526B3FCB811A%3A%2FAppName.
Timeout was = 15000
Session=ccmpp03-2018026140450-10

I think, EP has some default timeout of 15 sec.
1)Is there a way to increase it?
2)Is there any other solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check this:
[How to change the default Avaya Voice Browser (AVB) timeout value from an Avaya Voice Portal system?](https://www.devconnectprogram.com/site/global/products_resources/avaya_aura_experience_portal/support/faq/index.gsp#110)

Answer (score 1):

you can change fetch time in AEP that is for all the application configured in AEP. if you want to change the fetch time for single speech application you need to add a property in the root then configured the fetch time for individual speech application.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFBHY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wHL4.png)